# Как объединить две таблицы не размножая строки?

Tags: sql, oracle

Таблица 1:

| id | data1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 |
| 1 | b1 |
| 2 | c1 |
| 2 | d1 |
| 2 | e1 |

Таблица 2:

| id | data2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a2 |
| 1 | b2 |
| 1 | c2 |
| 2 | d2 |
| 2 | e2 |

Необходимый результат:

| id | data1 | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | a2 |
| 1 | b1 | b2 |
| 1 |  | c2 |
| 2 | c1 | d2 |
| 2 | d1 | e2 |
| 2 | e1 |  |

Comment: С учетом того, что у вас связи много ко многим, ближе к никак. По какой логике строки должны объеденяться?

Comment: @Swad логику вижу простую - свалить всё в кучу по id в порядке следования

Comment: ROW_NUMBER, потом JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        COALESCE(T1.id, T2.id) AS id
        ,T1."data" AS data1
        ,T2."data" AS data2
FROM T1
FULL JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id AND LEFT(T1."data", 1) = LEFT(T2."data", 1)
ORDER BY id, data1, data2
```

Только результат будет не как в описании, без пары будут с1 и с2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не совсем то что я имел ввиду, поля data между собой ни как не связаны, только поле id

Comment: В Оракле нет функции LEFT. Вопрос точно про Оракл, а не про MSSQL?

Comment: @ESkri писал на MS SQL, значит LEFT нужно заменить на аналог в OracleDB

Comment: @Ставер видимо не так понял, сорян

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь, получилось с подсказкой Akina.

```
select nvl(t1.ID,t2.ID) as ID,
       t1.DATA,
       t2.DATA
  from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by T.ID order by T.ID) as R,
       T.ID,
       T.DATA
  from TABLE1 T) T1
 full join (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by T.ID order by T.ID) as R,
       T.ID,
       T.DATA
  from TABLE2 T) T2
 on T1.r = T2.r and t1.id = t2.id
```